# Errors while installing Drools Workbench 6.2.0 using tomcat

Tags: drools, drools-guvnor, drools-flow, kie-workbench

I am new to Drools.I am trying to install Drools workbench 6.2.0 in Tomcatserver.I follwed the instructions given in the readme.txt.I have follwed all the steps mentiondBut when I start my Tomcat server,I am getting the following exception.

```
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Invalid persistence.xml.
Error parsing XML (line-1 : column -1): cvc-complex-type.4: Attribute 'value' must appear on element 'property'.
Error parsing XML (line-1 : column -1): cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'property' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty.
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.PersistenceXmlLoader.loadURL(PersistenceXmlLoader.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.packaging.PersistenceXmlLoader.deploy(PersistenceXmlLoader.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:327)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:58)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
    at org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryManager.getOrCreate(EntityManagerFactoryManager.java:49)
    at org.kie.workbench.drools.backend.server.BpmDependenciesProducer.getEntityManagerFactory(BpmDependenciesProducer.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1660)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Aug 25, 2015 11:57:18 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: ContextListener: contextDestroyed()
Aug 25, 2015 11:58:49 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception List with 1 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: org.jbpm.domain] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:925)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:900)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:59)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:63)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)
    at org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryManager.getOrCreate(EntityManagerFactoryManager.java:49)
    at org.kie.workbench.drools.backend.server.BpmDependenciesProducer.getEntityManagerFactory(BpmDependenciesProducer.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:267)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:263)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invokeOnInstance(WeldMethodImpl.java:164)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstance(MethodInjectionPoint.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ProducerMethod$ProducerMethodProducer.produce(ProducerMethod.java:136)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractProducerBean$AbstractProducer.produce(AbstractProducerBean.java:321)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractProducerBean.create(AbstractProducerBean.java:310)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:626)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:692)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:136)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:796)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:805)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget$1$1.proceed(ManagedBean.java:165)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget$1.work(ManagedBean.java:161)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$FixInjectionPoint.run(ManagedBean.java:135)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget.inject(ManagedBean.java:157)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:297)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:626)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractReceiverBean.getReceiver(AbstractReceiverBean.java:77)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractProducerBean$AbstractProducer.produce(AbstractProducerBean.java:319)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.AbstractProducerBean.create(AbstractProducerBean.java:310)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.unbound.DependentContextImpl.get(DependentContextImpl.java:68)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:626)
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:692)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.FieldInjectionPoint.inject(FieldInjectionPoint.java:136)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectBoundFields(Beans.java:796)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.Beans.injectFieldsAndInitializers(Beans.java:805)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget$1$1.proceed(ManagedBean.java:165)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.InjectionContextImpl.run(InjectionContextImpl.java:48)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget$1.work(ManagedBean.java:161)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$FixInjectionPoint.run(ManagedBean.java:135)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean$ManagedBeanInjectionTarget.inject(ManagedBean.java:157)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.ManagedBean.create(ManagedBean.java:297)
    at org.jboss.weld.context.AbstractContext.get(AbstractContext.java:103)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ContextBeanInstance.getInstance(ContextBeanInstance.java:90)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:79)
    at org.jbpm.services.cdi.impl.store.DeploymentSyncManager$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.toString(DeploymentSyncManager$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at org.kie.internal.runtime.cdi.BootOnLoadExtension.runPostConstruct(BootOnLoadExtension.java:68)
    at org.kie.internal.runtime.cdi.BootOnLoadExtension.afterDeploymentValidation(BootOnLoadExtension.java:59)
    at org.kie.internal.runtime.cdi.BootOnLoadExtension$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.afterDeploymentValidation(BootOnLoadExtension$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.java)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$13.work(SecureReflections.java:267)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAsInvocation(SecureReflectionAccess.java:137)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.invoke(SecureReflections.java:263)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldMethodImpl.invokeOnInstance(WeldMethodImpl.java:164)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.ForwardingWeldMethod.invokeOnInstance(ForwardingWeldMethod.java:51)
    at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:245)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:233)
    at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:213)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractContainerEvent.fire(AbstractContainerEvent.java:75)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:46)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.fire(AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.java:31)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:382)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener.contextInitialized(Listener.java:182)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1660)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [java:comp/env/jdbc/jbpm]
    at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1827)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1785)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:96)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:915)
    ... 87 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: no resource registered with uniqueName 'jdbc/jbpm', available resources: []
    at bitronix.tm.resource.ResourceObjectFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceObjectFactory.java:55)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory.getObjectInstance(ResourceFactory.java:143)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:843)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:831)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:135)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:421)
    at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:65)
    ... 100 more
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.fire(AbstractDeploymentContainerEvent.java:48)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.events.AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.fire(AfterDeploymentValidationImpl.java:31)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:382)
    at org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.Listener.contextInitialized(Listener.java:182)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1660)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: File `persistence.xml` seems to be broken.

Comment: But I didn't do any changes in persistence.xml.It is  a fresh install of kie-drools-wb-distribution-wars-6.2.0.Final-tomcat7.war file.:(

Comment: Can someone tell which is the stable version of Drools workbench?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend trying Wildfly-8.2.1 with Drools-Workbench-6.2.  I had similar issues with Tomcat 8 that did not exist with Wildfly 8.